# Export AOT objects (XPO) with or without IDs?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, aot, dynamics-ax-xpo

I have this situation where we have a production Dynamics 2009 AX (RTM) environment whose AOT we used to do a code update project to RU8.

So now, I have a production environment (RTM) and one that is the same but patched to RU8.

The thing is that since, Page Definitions have changed in the RTM environment and I want to export those to the RU8 environment.

I can export an XPO of the whole tree (Web->Web Files->Page definitions) and import it in the RU8 env. but do I export with or without IDs ? Does this change anything if objects exist in both environments ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Almost in any situation you should prefere to **EXPORT** WITH IDs. There is nothing you can lost with this.
- You should prefere to **IMPORT** WIDTH IDs when you want to maintain two copies of the same environment (DEV, TEST, ...).
- You has to **IMPORT** WIDHOUT IDs when you import objects in an environment that has not been in that environment before, nor in a copy of this environment. For example, when you import objects from another company or created by another developer. This usually has to be done in development environment and then export-import WITH IDs to the next apps (TEST, PRODUCTION, ...)

When you import objects WITHOUT IDs, the system will assign new IDs to the objects for this application, so you won't be abble to export-import WITH IDs to another copies of the app. This will lead to problems soon or late so it should be avoided.

There are exceptions to this rule but to be sure of picking the right option in any situation you have to understand well this best practices.

Comment: why would you need Id's to be the same in 2 environments? i disagree and always export/import without id's to avoid all these problems entirely.

Comment: For example, you loose the possibility of copying an entire application through copying the AOD files of the App folder. You can't do this if you don't maintain IDs.

Comment: You can, of course, work without maintaining IDs... many people do it. I just answered the way of working to maintain them, which is the matter of the original question.

Comment: hmm not worth the risk just for that - i have never seen a live situation where that has been an issue. your answer didnt really say why.

Comment: You can imagine how important is the ID problem looking to the great effort that Microsoft has done in AX 2012 to minimice it with the new "models".

Comment: They really are! But this great process designed to move the entire Model Store in two stages that allow you to copy changes between environments in a few minutes... comes to replace the "old" way of copying AOD files what many people used in previous versions (like me). Those (old and new model) ways have many advantages versus XPO import, the most important I think are that they can be automated and that the objects are copied compiled, so that you don't need to compile the destination app after the update, saving time in the process.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39244/discussion-between-j-a-estevan-and-anthonyblake)